# Display attribute from XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to display the id attribute of a [CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_disc) from the following XML file. I display everything correctly except the id.

**Display code**

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load( 'insert.xml' );

    $CATEGORIES = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "CD" );

    foreach( $CATEGORIES as $CD )
    {
        $TITLES = $CD->getElementsByTagName( "TITLE" );
        $TITLE = $TITLES->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $BANDS= $CD->getElementsByTagName( "BAND" );
        $BAND= $BANDS->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $YEARS = $CD->getElementsByTagName( "YEAR" );
        $YEAR = $YEARS->item(0)->nodeValue;

        echo "<b>$TITLE - $BAND - $YEAR\n</b><br>";
    }
?>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MY_CD>
    <CATEGORIES>
        <CD id="3231">
            <TITLE>NEVER MIND THE BOLLOCKS</TITLE>
            <BAND>SEX PISTOLS</BAND>
            <YEAR>1977</YEAR>
        </CD>
        <CD id="2453">
            <TITLE>NEVERMIND</TITLE>
            <BAND>NIRVANA</BAND>
            <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
        </CD>
    </CATEGORIES>
</MY_CD>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php):

```
$id = $CD->getAttribute('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), it's easy to manage and more suitable for your example. Attributes are accessible like this:

```
$id = $CD['id'];
```